How to use docker api in dind
I'm using docker in docker. I ran:
docker run --privileged -it docker:dind sh
I already found that I must unset DOCKER_HOST env error-during-connect-get-http-docker-2375-ping to use inner docker.
But how can I use docker api, with non set DOCKER_HOST?
I tried set daemon.json:
{
    "hosts": ["unix:///var/run/docker.sock", "tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"]
}

then I get error: "Get “http://docker:2375/_ping”: dial tcp: lookup docker on 10.10.15.22:53: server misbehaving"

As with any other service in a container, you need to expose its API endpoint, usually with a docker run -p option, or you can make a Unix socket visible by bind-mounting the directory containing the socket (on a native-Linux host without Docker Desktop).  Docker-in-Docker is a somewhat advanced setup and shouldn't be necessary in most cases; hopefully these concepts are familiar to you already.

Its not clear from your question context if you need to unset DOCKER_HOST. The official docker images manage this variable automatically if it is not set.
A minimal example of using docker:dind would be this compose file:
compose.yaml
volumes:
  certs:

services:
  docker:
    image: docker:dind
    privileged: true
    volumes:
    - certs:/certs

  cli:
    image: docker:cli
    depends_on:
    - docker
    volumes:
    - certs:/certs

Check that it works:
docker compose run cli docker info

Images based off docker:* have an entry-point that automatically manages DOCKER_HOST by checking if /var/run/docker.sock is mounted, or DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR is unset or not.
If you are using some other image that you have installed the docker cli into, then you will need to manage dockers configuration yourself. For example add this to the compose.yaml file
  alpine:
    image: alpine
    depends_on:
    - docker
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
      DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
      DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
    volumes:
    - certs:/certs
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - |
      apk add docker
      docker info

And verify that the docker cli can connect:
docker compose run alpine

In the context of GitLab - where the linked error goes, you want a gitlab runner with the following critical config.toml settings. Namely the docker:dind service needs to be run in privileged mode. There is no separate setting for services. "/certs" must be shared between the dind and other docker containers so they can negotiate the tls connection.
  ...
  [runners.docker]
    image = "docker:cli"
    privileged = true
    volumes = ["/certs", "/cache"]
    ...

.gitlab-ci.yml
build with docker:
  stage: build
  image: docker:cli
  services:
    - name: docker:dind
  script:
    - docker info

build with alpine:
  stage: build
  image: alpine:latest
  services:
  - docker:dind
  variables:
    DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker:2376
    DOCKER_CERT_PATH: /certs/client
    DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 1
  script:
  - apk add docker
  - docker info

